# Writer has_many Book has_many Order. How to ensure Writer.books.each, orders.empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a `Writer` model that has_many `books`.  Each `book` has_many `orders`. In order to prevent unwanted deletions, the `Book` model has a before_destroy hook method to make sure it isn't referenced in the `Order` model, as suggested in [PragProg Agile Web Dev (p.7)](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/cart.pdf)

**Book.rb**

```
before_destroy: :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_order

def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_order
  if orders.empty?
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

**How would I write a before_destroy hook method for the Writer model so that for Writer.books.each, no orders exist?** I started writing the below, but can't figure out exactly how to write it.

**Writer.rb**

```
before_destroy: :ensure_books_not_referenced_by_any_order

def ensure_books_not_referenced_by_any_order
  self.books.each do |book|
    if book.orders.empty?
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get @Mark's suggestion to work. Resorted to restricting only for books.empty?, meaning a writer must delete all of his books first in order to delete his own profile.

```
def ensure_has_no_books
  if books.empty?
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you have insight on how I can get the has_no_books_reference_by_any_order loop to work, and I will accept if it does. Thanks!

Comment: The code looks still correct. BTW: You can shorten your method to `return self.books.empty?`. And don't forget to correct the before_destroy-hook: `before_destroy :ensure_has_no_books`. Hm, is your doublecolon after 'before_destroy' by intentionally? This shouldn't be there...

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Fixed the typos, but still can't get yours to work... I think I'll go with the simpler solution, as it may actually be good to prevent users from destroying their own profiles unless they are really sure (and show it by deleting their own books).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't abort your loop on the first book without orders.

```
def ensure_books_not_referenced_by_any_order
    self.books.each do |book|
        if !book.order.empty?
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

Comment: thanks @Mark. This is still letting me destroy users that have books with orders. I think it's close, so let me play with it...

Comment: Hi @Mark, I've resorted to a less ideal solution as shown in my answer. Please let me know if you have an idea of why your code doesn't work in this particular case.

Comment: There's a typo in my method, it should be `if !book.orders.empty?` (pluralized order), but you surely sorted that out.